# If-else in React Stateless functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am basically refactoring my React component to support new stateless functional component [React functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components). However, I'm confused about the `if-else` syntax in functional component.

Old code (Working fine): What it does basically is to find if the user is currently logged in. If yes, redirect to Home page else to Landing page. CurrentUser component returns a prop `currentUser` and checks the current state

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import currentUser from "shared/components/CurrentUser";
import Home from "../Home";
import Landing from "../Landing";

class DefaultRouteHandler extends Component {

    render() {
        if (!this.props.currentUser) {
            return (<Landing />);
        } else {
            return (<Home />);
        }
    }
}

export default currentUser(DefaultRouteHandler);
```

New code: Now, how should I check the `else` condition in case the state of currentUser is false. As you can see right now it will always return the Home page.

```
import React from "react";
import currentUser from "shared/components/CurrentUser";
import Home from "../Home";
import Landing from "../Landing";

const DefaultRouteHandler = ({currentUser}) => (
    <Home />
);

export default DefaultRouteHandler;
```

Finally in my route.jsx I am calling the aforementioned component

```
<IndexRoute component={DefaultRouteHandler} />
```

Let me know if you need more information. I can also paste my `CurrentUser` component code. However, I don't think it will serve any purpose for this question.

Comment: have you tried doing something like this `!currentUser ? <Landing /> : <Home />` ?

Comment: This is not a valid syntax when transpiling jsx using Babel

Comment: I tried it with the babeljs.io online repl, seems to be working. It transpiles to this code `var DefaultRouteHandler = function DefaultRouteHandler(_ref) {
    var currentUser = _ref.currentUser;
    return !currentUser ? React.createElement(Landing, null) : React.createElement(Home, null);
};`, I used this `const DefaultRouteHandler = ({currentUser}) => (
    !currentUser ? <Landing /> : <Home />
);`

Comment: Yep, sorry I didn't react the code properly. It is valid indeed, but it does not work and always returns `<Landing />`

Comment: I think the problem is, you're not passing the `currentUser` props to the stateless function. On your old code, you have access to `this.props` but on the stateless function, you can only access what you input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. I have to make 2 changes in my new code:

1) Use ternary operator for if-else

2) Forgot to pass `currentUser` wrapper in export default in order to access the actual prop value

Following code works:

```
import React from "react";
import currentUser from "shared/components/CurrentUser";
import Home from "../Home";
import Landing from "../Landing";

const DefaultRouteHandler = ({currentUser}) => (
    !currentUser ? <Landing /> : <Home />
);

export default currentUser(DefaultRouteHandler);
```

thanks @Road for reminding me that I am not passing the prop from `currentUser` component.

Answer (score 8):

```
const DefaultRouteHandler = ({currentUser}) => {
  if (currentUser) {
    return <Home />;
  }
  return <Landing />;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This is called [Conditional-Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

1) Use simple if-else.

```
const DefaultRouteHandler = ({currentUser}) => {
    if (currentUser) {
      return <Home />;
    }
    return <Landing />;
};
```

2) Use JavaScript Ternary Operator

```
const DefaultRouteHandler = ({currentUser}) => (
    currentUser ? <Home /> : <Landing />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

use condition in stateless component for showing more than one imported component.
Show condition wise header in your spa
    In App.js file

```js
var path= window.location.pathname; // lets imaging that url is "/home/x"
         var pathArray = path.split( '/' );
         var loc= pathArray[1];//number of part of url that is changing, here it rerurns x
         
        injectTapEventPlugin();
        export default ({ children }) => (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
            <div className="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
            {loc!=="signin" && path!=="/"?(<DashboardHeader/>):null}
            {loc!=="signin" && path!=="/"?(<SideBar/>):null}
                {children}
              </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
    
        );
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer here as it is the most flexible